# Read HTML Body from Outlook MSG file

Tags: .net, delphi, outlook

How can I read the HTML body from an Outlook.MSG file using Delphi code.

I have been using Scalabiums smmsg component, but it only the body text returns a value, the the html body property always returns an empty string.

Thanks,

Phillip.

Answer (score 1):

I've always had good luck using the Outlook Redemption library. Check it out here http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains the .net tag so maybe this thread is helpful:

[How to convert .msg to .eml](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/b5a1f22d-c94c-43c9-8bf8-2027a77bdc5d)

For example:

> Save a mail as a file with MailMessage :
>
> ```
> _SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = "C:\\";
>
> _SmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
>
> _SmtpClient.Send(_Mail);
> ```

Then, Indy (Internet Direct) can be used which provides a procedure in the `TIdMessage` class (unit IdMessage) to read a SMTP message from file

```
procedure TIdMessage.LoadFromFile(const AFileName: string; 
                                  const AHeadersOnly: Boolean = False);
```